# Discord.js - Erela.js - Lavalink | Check if no results are returned from Lavalink

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to detect if there are truly no matches found by Lavalink since I sometimes don't get a match for a song of which I'm sure it exists.
This is how I get the search results :

```
const searchResults = await client.music.search(query, message.author);
```

Now I want to check up to 5 times if there truly are no matches so I first need to know if there are no matches. I don't know how to check if there are no matches and I've already tried this :

```
if (!searchResults)
if (searchResults == undefined)
if (searchResults == null)
```

And `console.log(searchResults)` doesn't log anything to the console when there are no matches.

Edit : my current solution which I know is not the best and I would really like to hear your suggestions

```
let searchResults;
try {
    searchResults = await client.music.search(query, message.author);
} catch (error1) {
    try {
        searchResults = await client.music.search(query, message.author);
    } catch (error2) {
        try {
            searchResults = await client.music.search(query, message.author);
        } catch (error3) {
            try {
                searchResults = await client.music.search(query, message.author);
            } catch (error4) {
                try {
                    searchResults = await client.music.search(query, message.author);
                } catch (error5) {
                    const musicničnašel = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("** GLASBA **")
                    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
                    .setDescription(`**Nisem našel glasbe na podlagi iskalnega niza:** ${query}
                    **Če si prepričan, da je bila to napaka, poskusi še enkrat!**`)
                    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
                    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

                return message.channel.send(musicničnašel).then(d_msg => {d_msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 })});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a recursive function to get rid of the nested blocks.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
const MAX_NO_OF_TRIALS = 5;

async function search(client, query, author, trialNumber = 0) {

    try {

        // Do the actual search here like the following
        const result = await client.music.search(query, author)
        
        if (result.exception || !(result.tracks.length || result.playlist.tracks.length))
             throw new Error("no result found")
        
        return result

    } catch (error) {
        if (trialNumber < MAX_NO_OF_TRIALS) {
            console.log(`trial #${trialNumber + 1}`)
            return await search(client, query, author, ++trialNumber)
        }
        else
            throw error
    }
}




// then you can use it inside an async block like:

try {

    let searchResults = await search(client, query, message.author)

    // do stuff with searchResults

} catch (error) {
    // Error persists after 5 (MAX_NO_OF_TRIALS) trials
    console.log("cant handle it")
}
```

Here we defined a custom search function that accepts "client", "query" and "author". So we have to do, `await search(client, query, message.author)` instead of `client.music.search(query, message.author)`.

The custom search function would start with `trialNumber` = 0 and  `MAX_NO_OF_TRIALS` being 5. If  there is an error the search would call itself recursively unless `trialNumber` gets beyond `MAX_NO_OF_TRIALS`. (you can set  `MAX_NO_OF_TRIALS` to any number of maximum number of tries to modify the behavior.

Created the check based on the implementation from:  [SearchResult.ts implementation here](https://github.com/WarHammer414/erela.js/blob/master/src/lib/entities/SearchResult.ts)